# Define correct `fixture_path` for cucumber

Tags: rspec, cucumber, fixtures

I want to attach a file, from a cucumber step:

```
When /^I attach an image/ do
  page.attach_file("Image", File.join(fixture_path, "green_small.jpg"))
end
```

For some reason this results in `/home/xxx/test/fixtures/green_small.jpg`. Somewhere the default for fixture_path is `test/fixtures` in cucumber.

I am using rspec, so the path to the fixtures should be `spec/fixtures`. My Rspec `spec_helper.rb` has this configured:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
end
```

I have already tried setting this in `config/environments/test.rb` without success.

Obviously, I can simply build the path myself, `page.attach_file("Image", File.join(Rails.root, "spec", "fixtures", "green_small.jpg"))` works. But that `fixture_path` is already there. Setting that correct and then using it, would make the steps just a little more portable and cleaner.

But this is not used by Cucumber. How do I get the correct url in cucumber?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you define Cucumber global variables in `World` which is a rb file in `features/support`

File `features/support/path_define.rb`

```
module PathDefine
  def my_fixture_path
    @my_fixture_path ||= "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  end
end

World(PathDefine)
```

Then you can use `my_fixture_path` variable anywhere in step definitions.

Reference: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/A-Whole-New-World

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://cassiomarques.wordpress.com/2009/01/23/how-to-test-file-uploads-with-cucumber/) post, you should use the path in the test, not a environment

Like this:

```
attach_file(:csv_file, File.join(RAILS_ROOT, 'features', 'upload-files', 'products_csv_ok.csv'))
```

Comment: Well, obviously I can set the path in the steps myself (I will update the question to reflect that). Thing is, I /have/ a helper variable (method?) called "fixtures_path" which already contains the path to a directory. Only it is the wrong path. Setting that correct and then using it, would make the steps a tad cleaner.

Comment: You can create a method in spec_helper.rb called "fixtures_path" and return the correct path. I think that will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note, the reason why you can't put this into your environments/*.rb files is that this config block is for `RSpec.config` ... not for `YourAppName::Application.configure`

You have to modify the path in your `./spec/spec_helper.rb` file.